# Slicing a table holding its first line or header intact

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table structure in html:

```
<table id="table">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Place</td>
                <td>Population</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Phoenix city</td>
                <td>1445632</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>San Antonio city</td>
                <td>1327407</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>San Diego city</td>
                <td>1307402</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Dallas city</td>
                <td>1197816</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>San Jose city</td>
                <td>945942</td>

            </tr>
    </table>
```

Jquery this need by slicing table so that the first row (header) seje not removed, leaving something like that.

```
<table id="table">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Place</td>
                <td>Population</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Dallas city</td>
                <td>1197816</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>San Jose city</td>
                <td>945942</td>

            </tr>
    </table>
```

I'm using the **file reader api** javascript to read `.csv` to tables and need to filter the content that is displayed by slicing some parts of this table.

I'm slicing this way:

```
reader.readAsBinaryString(file.slice(0, 10 * 1024 * 1024));
```

My full code in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/NjPz2/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding the file reading part, this jQuery code slices out rows 1-3 of the table in your post:

```
$('#table').html($('#table tr').not($('#table tr').slice(1,4)));
```

Are you wanting to limit the rows displayed while reading the CSV? If so, what are your criteria for showing or hiding rows?